# Can I use (interact with) Siri without light the screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

When I interact with Siri, I don't want to turn on the screen, because I don't need to read the response, I only need to hear it. It is a waste of energy with a lit screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  This is not possible.  There are no configurable options to diable Siri screen dialogs.

> I don't want to turn on the screen, because I don't need to read the response, I only need to hear it.

Siri (and Siri's developers) can't predict when you're going to read the screen or when you're only going to want to hear it. So, it is unlikely that this will change; Siri responds with *both* visual and auditory queues.

Comment: At least give an option, default is to open screen, nothing hurts.